# How can I be sure that Mathematica can or can't solve this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve the following equation for $x$:

```
eq = (g^2 π^2)/(128 x^2) + (4 x^2 y)/π - 1/16 k^2 Log[(2 x)/(π q)] == c
Solve[eq, x]
```

in which all the parameters are positive. Running this code for a long time does not lead to answer. How can I be sure that Mathematica can or can't solve this equation?

Comment: In general, practically speaking, I don't think you can be sure, unless one has special knowledge about the equation and techniques to solve it.  In cases such as this in which there are parameters, you can replace them by typical exact values, like this: `Solve[eq /. {g -> 1, k -> 1, q -> 1, c -> 1}, x]` (result `Solve::nsmet`, can't be solved). It's usually much faster, since the complexity of analyzing parameters usually grows extremely fast with the number of parameters. If the special case cannot be solved, then probably the general case cannot be solved either.

Comment: Here's a small suggestion that often helps, but alas not here:  merge and eliminate unneeded variables:  let $g^2 \pi^2/128 = a$, let $4 y/\pi = b$, and so on.  Then let $x^2 = z$ (a new variable).  I think, though, that for your particular equation there is no closed-form solution.

Comment: `Solve` is likely to spend serious time trying transformations to obtain a solution using `ProductLog`. I doubt one exists though.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks a lot. Yes, by this way one can check if the equation can be solved or not by spending little time.

Comment: @David G. Stork Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau Thanks for your comment.

Comment: As a rough rule of thumb, the presence of transcendental functions generally reduces the odds of getting an a closed form solution for the equation, barring certain special cases.

Answer (score 2):

The equation can be set into a form

$$ 
\dfrac{A}{x^2} + B x^2 y = P \log x +Q $$

so it can be solved  ***algebraically,*** no need to use `Mathematica`:

$$  y(x) = \dfrac{ P \log x  + Q - \dfrac{A}{x^2}  }{Bx^2}$$

For some arbitrarily chosen constants the above is plotted... and level contour lines can be drawn if so required.

It may help to understand the physical significance of the constants in the phenomenon.

EDIT1:

You can also get $x=f(y)$ at uniform $y$ increments with numerical integration of ode

$$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\frac{B x^5}{Px^2-2 Bx^4 y -2A} ;$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact I need the analytic solution of the equation. Using numerical methods I could move the issue forward. I wonder if the analytic solution can be found.

Comment: Can be found as $y=f(x) $ added in answer.

Comment: I want to find x not y.

Comment: No analytical solution for transcendental functions. ..A table of $ x\; vs \;y $ for uniform x increments is straightaway possible numerically . Using a differential equation $ y \;vs\; x$  can be also tabulated as a workaround. Do you want it?